# What to return as onRetryAsync?

Tags: c#, polly

I am trying to implement a retry policy that will retry if an exception is thrown.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get the signature for the onRetryAsync block right. The compiler says "Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type...."

[The documentation suggests to return Task.CompletedTask](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/247#issuecomment-438335852) but that's apparently not available to me in the current libraries I am forced to use.

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
                    .Handle<SigsThrottledException>(e => e.RetryAfterInSeconds > 0)
                    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                        retryCount: 3,
                        sleepDurationProvider: (i, e, ctx) =>
                        {
                            var ste = (SigsThrottledException)e;
                            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)ste.RetryAfterInSeconds);
                        },
                        onRetryAsync: (e, ts, i, ctx) =>
                        {
                            // Logging goes here
                        });

<....>

var response = await retryPolicy.Execute(async () =>
        {
            Uri substrateurl = new Uri("https://substrate.office.com/");
            return await SIGSClient.Instance.PostAsync(client, substrateurl, new UserInfo(), "faketoken", new Signal(), Guid.NewGuid()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        );
```

Comment: `Task.CompletedTask` should be part of `System.Threading.Tasks`

Comment: I know. It's not in my case. I have no idea why.

Comment: And anyway that doesn't matter, as I would like to execute logging code in the onRetryAsync block.

Comment: Well if the logging code is async then you can make the lambda async `async (e, tx, i, ctx) => { await logger.SomeAsyncCall(...); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So: This is a case of the compiler being less than helpful, compounded by the fact that async/await etc. is still fairly new to me, and not always that easy to figure out.

Essentially I was missing one thing:

```
onRetryAsync: async (e, ts, i, ctx) =>
```

...an async in front of the signature, which by the way was not present in the code examples I was linking to.

The type of the onRetryAsync argument is `Func<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task>` and one can be declared like this:

```
Func<Exception, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> nopBlock = async (e, ts, i, ctx) =>
        {
            // Do something here
            // The "something" should be async
        };
```

I eventually figured this out by looking up the signature of the WaitAndRetryAsync overload that I was calling.